# Trying to delete all files in all subfolders with a Powershell script, but can't find a way to exclude the deletion of files in the root folder

Tags: windows, powershell, file, automation, subdirectory

I wrote a Powershell script that deletes all files in the subfolders of the current path.
It works fine, but it also deletes all files in the current/root folder. How can I exclude that folder?

```
$CountedFiles = (Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count
$NewCountedFiles = ($CountedFiles - 1)
$path = Get-Location
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.* -Exclude *.ps1 -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

Write-Host "Es wurde(n) '$NewCountedFiles' Datei(en) in allen Unterordnern und im derzeitigen Ordner im Pfad: '$path' gelöscht!" 

pause
```

Currently I have it so that it exludes the .ps1 (Powershell Script File) for testing so it doesn't deletes itself.

I tried to find a way to exclude the root folder, but haven't found one since I am new to Powershell. I hope that someone knows an easy why to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to delete the files, but not the subfolders, you can try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $pwd -File -Recurse
$filesToDelete = $files | Where-Object { $_.Directory.FullName -ne $pwd }
$filesToDelete | Remove-Item -Force
```

And you delete all the files without remove the root content and the subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the top-level subdirectory children of the current location instead of starting at the current location itself:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach { 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_ | Sort-Object -Property FullName | ForEach {
    $_.Delete() 
  }
}
```

That will delete subdirectories as well as files; if you only want to delete the files, go with Victor Silva's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the nice supplement, I will run with Victor's answer, but I am bookmarking this answer if I have to do it this way at some point ^^

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell-idiomatic solution that takes advantage of direct pipeline support in [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) and [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Remove-Item):

```bash
Get-ChildItem $path -Directory |  # Get only the subdirectires
  Get-ChildItem -Include *.* -Exclude *.ps1 -File -Recurse | # Look for files in each
  Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

If you add [`-OutVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) `files` to the 2nd `Get-ChildItem` call, you can use `$files.Count` to get the count of deleted files later.